Why does one process not reach `exit(0)` when forking?
I have the following program, just to test if I'm understanding forking and shared memory.  In summary it makes shared memory, forks, forks, forks, and in each fork, writes data and exits.
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <sys/wait.h>

#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>

int main() {
    
    key_t key = ftok(".", 'x');
    int shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(int)*4, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    if (shmid < 0) {
        perror("shmget\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int *arr = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
    pid_t c1 = fork();
    if (c1==0) {
        pid_t c2 = fork();
        if (c2==0) {
            pid_t c3 = fork();
            if (c3==0) {
                arr[0] = 10;
            } else {
                arr[1] = 11;
            }
            exit(0);
        } else {
            arr[2] = 12;
        }
        exit(0);
    } else {
        arr[3] = 13;
        wait(NULL);
        wait(NULL);
        wait(NULL);

        for (int i=0; i<4; i++) printf("%d ", arr[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    exit(0);
}

This prints 0 11 12 13 showing that for some reason the value 10 is never assigned to arr[0].
I expected that every process would reach some call to exit(0).  Especially the one after the third fork, I would think should reach the same call to exit(0) that is reached by the second fork.
However, when I add an explicit call to exit inside the third fork's block (i.e. after c3==0), it then executes as expected.
As I write this, it suddenly occurs to me a guess about why this is happening:  Is it because the second child reaches exit before the third, and because it exits then the link from the fourth to the parent is broken?

You should add a fourth wait(NULL);. Or, better yet: while (wait(NULL) >= 0);

you can only wait() for your own children. Calling wait(NULL) 3 times in the original parent process will not wait for the grandchildren.

Check what those wait calls returns. I'll bet that at least one of them will fail (since you don't start all child-processes in the first, original, parent process).

@Barmar I was kind of wondering about that.  But all over the internet I see things like what Craig Estey writes above, which seems to suggest that you can call wait in the same place repeatedly.  In any case, I moved the waits to other places and now I'm getting a mysterious invalid argument error for shmget.  It seems to have something to do with using already allocated memory, but I'm not sure why.  In any case, it's likely unrelated to the above issue so I probably need to figure this out somewhere else.

You can call wait() multiple times, as long as you have child processes created by the original parent process. But your code doesn't do that, it creates only one child process. And that child-process in turn creates a new child-process, making the original parent process a grandparent. That grandchild needs to be waited for by its own direct parent.

@Someprogrammerdude Right, that makes sense -- but I have seen, like Craig has suggested, doing this even when there are grandchildren.  I'm pretty sure in at least one web page and one YouTube video I've seen people write this.  I'm not sure if that's just incorrect or something else is going on that I don't understand.

Either they're also wrong or you misread it. It can be confusing to determine whether the parent makes multiple children of its own or they're created by the children.

Try adding code to each process to print getpid() and getppid() so you'll see the relationships.

On Linux, you can use prctl() from <sys/prctl.h> along with PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER (see prctl(2)) so that the current process does reap all its descendants (instead of letting the system process reap its indirect descendants).

Unfortunately, for every good video or tutorial there are also ten that are not as good. Finding the good ones is not easy.

You currently try to wait for three processes in the original parent process but it has only one child, so only the first wait is successful. There's no guarantee that the other processes are ready with their writing to shared memory before you print the result.
In order to ensure that the children are all done, each parent could wait on its child.
Example:
pid_t c1 = fork();
if (c1==0) { // child
    pid_t c2 = fork();
    if (c2==0) { // child
        pid_t c3 = fork();
        if (c3==0) { // child
            arr[0] = 10;
            exit(0);
        } else {
            arr[1] = 11;
            waitpid(c3, NULL, 0); // waiting for child
        }
        exit(0);
    } else {
        arr[2] = 12;
        waitpid(c2, NULL, 0);    // waiting for child
    }
    exit(0);
} else {
    arr[3] = 13;
    waitpid(c1, NULL, 0);    // waiting for child
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
}


@zwol You must like symmetry very much. I love the edit you made to my answer and now I'm thinking, "should I remove all the exit(0)s" since you just made them redundant? :-) I wish there was a +1 button for edits.

All I was thinking was "this code would be less confusing to newbies if it clearly only called waitpid on the parent side of each fork"...
